# r.v. Law of the min

Tags: probability

On a probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$, and given a r.v. $(X,Y)$ with values in $R^2$. If the law of $(X,Y)$ is $\lambda \mu e^{-\lambda x - \mu y } 1_{R^2_+} (x,y) dx dy$, what is the law of the min $(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt to complete what Sasha started:

$\mathbb P(Z>z)=\mathbb P(X>z,Y>z)$

$=\mathbb P(X>z)\mathbb P(Y>z)$

$=\displaystyle \left(\int_{z}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\right)\left(\int_{z}^{\infty}\mu e^{-\mu y}dy\right)$

$=\left[\left.-e^{-\lambda x}\right|_{z}^{\infty}\right]  \left[\left.-e^{-\mu y}\right|_{z}^{\infty}\right]$

$= e^{-(\lambda +\mu)z}$

And then taking the negative of the derivative w.r.t $z\Rightarrow$ $\displaystyle (\lambda+\mu)e^{-(\lambda+\mu)z}\mathbb 1_{\mathbb R}(z)dz$, an exponential distribution.

Comment: There is a mistake in the evaluation of the integral. $\left[ -\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} \right]_{x=z}^{x \to \infty} = \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda z}$. The pdf is $-\partial_z \mathbb{P}(Z>z)$ giving the correct pdf you stated.

Comment: Ah I see it, corrected.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** 
Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Start by computing, for some $z>0$ 
$$
   1-F_Z(z) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z>z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X>z, Y>z\right)
$$
Notice that the probability of $(X,Y)$ factors, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are independent, hence
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left(X>z, Y>z\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X>z\right) \mathbb{P}\left(Y>z\right)
$$

Comment: Sasha: if you could, I'd appreciate if you could let me know if the answer I provided based on your hint is on the right track.